# Why is my while loop not iterating through completely?

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

So this is my code below, the goal is for this program is to check to see if the letters of the second string can be found in the first string. However I found the problem that i isn't, increasing in value. So the loop is only going through once. So this program ends at the first letter that it finds and returns true. How do I get i to increase so that it's iterating through every character of the string?

```
function mutation(arr) {
  var str = arr[1];
  str = str.toLowerCase().split("");
  var i = 0;
  while (i < arr.length) {
    if (arr[0].indexOf(str[i]) > -1) {
      //return  arr[i].indexOf(str[i], i);
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
    i++;
  }
}

mutation(["hello", "hey"]);
```

Comment: `return` will exit from your function, not from the while loop. What/when should the function return?

Comment: my guess is you don't want to `return true;` when you find a match, rather you want to set a boolean to true as long as your condition is met and return that boolean at the end

Comment: You're immediately returning from the function. Instead, you probably only want to return false if the letter *isn't* found then return true at the end to indicate that all letters were found.

Comment: You're returning before the increment.

Comment: @cmbuckley the function should return true only if all the characters found in the second string can be found in the first string

Comment: So you basically need to say that if the character is not found (i.e. `indexOf = -1`), then `return false`. Otherwise continue searching.

Answer (score 2):

This maybe?

```
function mutation(arr) {
  var str = arr[1];
  str = str.toLowerCase().split("");
  // iterating an array screams "for loop"
  for (var i=0; i < str.length; i++) {
    // if the letter was not found exit immediately
    if (arr[0].indexOf(str[i]) == -1) return false;
  }
  // since it didn't exit before, all the letters must have been found.
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function mutation(arr) {
  var base = arr[0],
      str = arr[1].toLowerCase().split(''),
      i = 0,
      match = true;
  while (i < str.length) {
    // if any target letter is not in base, return false
    if(base.indexOf(str[i]) === -1){
        return false;
    }
  }
  // otherwise they were all in, so return true
  return true;
}
mutation(["hello", "hey"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Totally different technique.

This function replaces, in the second string, all letters from the first string with empty space.  If the length is zero all letters were found.

```
function mutation(arr) {
  return arr[1].replace(new RegExp("[" + arr[0] + "]", "g"), "").length == 0;
}
```

Comment: PS this will totally break if you use anything other than simple letters/numbers in your arrays.